# Is Hub the DMZ in a Spoke-Hub architecture?

Tags: architecture

In a spoke hub architecture, is the DMZ another spoke (I.e. peered to the hub), a stand-alone vent, or the hub itself (for example as a subnet)?

This question is mostly for azure implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hub-spoke architecture refers to *site interconnects*. You've got a central hub (location) that all other sites connect to. All traffic between sites runs through the hub. *n* sites means you've got (*n*-1) links.

The exact opposite of hub-spoke is a full mesh. There's one connection between any two sites. Traffic only goes the shortest path but you've got *n*(*n*-1)/2 links. In practice you often have basic hub-spoke with some meshing for redundancy.

A DMZ is a zone in your *security model*. You can connect one on each site or just at the hub, depending on your requirements.